# What is the curve fitting model used for the "Qubit™ Protein Assay Kit"?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, proteins, commercial-products

This is the example of [Qubit™ Protein Assay](https://www.science.smith.edu/cmbs/wp-content/uploads/sites/36/2015/09/Qubit-Protein-Assay.pdf) curve.
It relates the concentration (x-axis) with fluorescence (y-axis).
**What is the curve-fitting method it use for this?** Clearly this is not simple linear fitting model.

[image]

Comment: It is clearly a non-linear fitting but the method used can not be identify only from the graph.

Comment: The caption to Fig. 3 in your link calls it a "modified Hill plot" without clarifying what modifications were made. I thought a Hill plot was of the log-log type which isn't the case here, so maybe they instead mean the fitted curve is an approximate solution of a (modified?) Hill equation.

Answer (score 2):

This is Fig 3 of the PDF that you linked to us, as pointed out in the [comment by Anyon](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9142/what-is-the-curve-fitting-model-used-for-qubit-protein-assay#comment19110_9142). The captio to Fig 3 is:

> "Figure  3. The  curve-fitting  algorithm  used  to  determine  concentration  in  the  Qubit™  protein  assay.  The  Qubit®  2.0 Fluorometer  generates  concentration  data  based  on  the  relationship  between  the  two  standards  used  in  calibration. This  plot  shows  the  line  corresponding  to  the  curve-fitting  algorithm  (a  modified  Hill  plot)  used  in  the  calculation  of concentration data for the Qubit™ protein assay. For reference, the positions of the standards and a set of data points from an actual experiment are shown superimposed onto the line, demonstrating that the curve-fitting algorithm gives accurate values for quantitation."

The curve in the figure also does look like one that you would get from a [Hill equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_equation_(biochemistry)) (nevermind the log-log "[Hill plot](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/CSU_Chico/CSU_Chico%3A_CHEM_451_-_Biochemistry_I/CHEM_451_Test/07%3A_Binding/7.3%3A_Model_Binding_Systems/C3._Mathematical_Analysis_of_Cooperative_Binding_-_Hill_Plot)" which is different). The word Hill only appears in that 9-page PDF document once (in precisely the quote figure caption above), so it doesn't look like they wanted to tell you any more.

At the top of the PDF we see two commercial company's names, [Invitrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invitrogen) and [Molecular Probes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_Probes) and the PDF is about the trademarked "Qubit™ Protein Assay Kits For use with the Qubit® 2.0 Fluorometer", which means that we're probably not dealing with open accecss science, but with commercial products, which rarely disclose details about calculations to the extent that (some!) scientists more often do when publishing academic papers.

You can try to contact them (all this information was fortunately in the PDF to which you provided a link), but I'm not sure if the model matters to you enough to bother with that:

> "Molecular Probes, Inc.  
> 29851 Willow Creek Road 
> Eugene, OR 97402
> Phone: (541) 465-8300 
> Fax: (541) 335-0504
>
> Customer Service:
> 6:00 am to 4:30 pm (Pacific Time) 
> Phone: (541) 335-0338 
> Fax: (541) 335-0305 
> probesorder@invitrogen.com
>
> Toll-Free Ordering for USA: 
> Order Phone: (800) 438-2209 
> Order Fax: (800) 438-0228
>
> Technical Service:8:00 am to 4:00 pm (Pacific Time)
> Phone: (541) 335-0353 
> Toll-Free (800) 438-2209 
> Fax: (541) 335-0238
> probestech@invitrogen.com
>
> Invitrogen European Headquarters Invitrogen, Ltd.
> 3 Fountain Drive
> Inchinnan Business Park Paisley PA4 9RF, UK 
> Phone: +44 (0) 141 814 6100 
> Fax: +44 (0) 141 814 6260 
> Email: euroinfo@invitrogen.com
> Technical Services: eurotech@invitrogen.com"

The link that you gave us happened to be hosted on a [Smith College](https://www.smith.edu) server for the "[Center for Molecular Biology (CMB)](https://www.science.smith.edu/cmbs)"  but there's not "About us" or "People" page so it's hard to see who the contact person would be. Likely the PDF was not on the Smith College website due to them having anything to do with product, other than the fact that it's [equipment](https://www.science.smith.edu/cmbs/equipment/) that's available to their students. The only email address I found on the CMB website after a few clicks and a couple minutes was given here:

> "Users will need to be granted access to use the equipment by the CMB’s ITI, Riccardo Racicot, at rracicot@smith.edu"